# Why can't I source my vimrc after installing vundle?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get my Vim to update on the fly after editing vimrc. So I followed the instructions at [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/updating-your-vimrc-file-on-the-fly/) which basically source vimrc every time you hit save.

But that doesn't work for some reason (when I save my vimrc it doesn't give any errors), so I decided to run `source $HOME/.vimrc` manually and here's what I got:

```
    -bash:  Configuration file for vim
            set nocompatible                              : command not found
    -bash:  Plugin Management {
            filetype off                                  : command not found
    -bash: .vimrc: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
    -bash: .vimrc: line 7: `        call vundle#rc()'
```

And here's my Vim info (I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.3):

```
    VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jul 31 2011 19:27:29)
    Compiled by root@apple.com
    Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
    -arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
    -clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
    -conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
    -dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path 
    +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv 
    +insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent 
    +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape 
    -mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse 
    +mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype 
    +path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile -python 
    -python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent 
    -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
    +tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
    -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
    +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
    -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
    system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
    user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
    user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
    fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
    Compilation: gcc -c -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
    Linking: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o vim -lncurses
```

Could anybody give me a hand here? Thanks so much!

== UPDATE ==

So as all of you have pointed out, I mixed up the Vim source and Bash source commands - Thanks.

Now I've tried running source within Vim and it worked without errors. However, it still doesn't seem to update my vimrc. I have this line in my vimrc

```
    nnoremap <leader><TAB> :sp ~/.vimrc<CR>
```

No matter whether I comment out the line, hitting `<leader><TAB>` after running `source ~/.vimrc` still opens up my vimrc in a split screen.

Comment: That output looks a little like you may have accidentally typed `:!source $HOME/.vimrc` (notice the bang)? instead of `:source $HOME/.vimrc`

Comment: You have a problem with your vimrc so you should show your vimrc. What are those `-bash:` things?

Comment: OK, you sourced your vim configuration file from your shell… but why?

Comment: Thanks guys I did mistakenly execute vimrc from Bash. Now I can run source without problems but still couldn't get vimrc to update on the fly. I'm going to edit my question please check back later!

Comment: `"No matter whether I comment out the line, hitting <leader><TAB> after running source ~/.vimrc still opens up my vimrc in a split screen"`: commenting the line that creates the mapping does not remove the it - you have to call `nunmap <leader><TAB>` and then source your .vimrc to check the changes.

Comment: Thanks, I think now I understand how vimrc works a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's `:source ...`, executed from within Vim. From your output, it appears that you have mistakenly executed it in the Bash shell itself (maybe via `:!source`); `source` also is a Bash built-in command (like `.`) to execute the file contents as Bash commands.

To debug the `:autocmd` that's not working for you, you could temporarily add

```
:echomsg "executing .vimrc"
```

or write the `.vimrc` with `:15verbose write` to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks you're exactly right. I've updated my question, please take a look.