# Can't source vimrc file with Vundle

Tags: vim, macos-sierra, vundle

I'm using Vundle as my vim plugin manager and I've noticed when I run

`source ~/.vimrc` it gives me a `vundle` loading error. However my plugins are working fine.

The error I get is

```
192-168-1-9:dotfiles sameeragayan$ source ~/.vimrc 
-bash: filetype: command not found
-bash:  set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/dotfiles/vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()



: No such file or directory
-bash: Plugin: command not found
-bash: /Users/sameeragayan/.vimrc: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /Users/sameeragayan/.vimrc: line 13: `call vundle#begin()'
```

When I check the path (`~/dotfiles/vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`) I can see the Vundle file is in the path

[image]

Below is my `vimrc` file (which is symlinked to `~/.vimrc`

```
set nocompatible " be iMproved, required
filetype off     " required
filetype plugin indent on
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/dotfiles/vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()



" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

call vundle#begin()

" other plugins plugins
" E.g Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'

call vundle#end()
```

My vim version is  - version 8.0.1100. MacOS version is - 10.12.5 (MacOSSierra).

PS: I did check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365129/why-cant-i-source-my-vimrc-after-installing-vundle) with no luck

Comment: Don't use bash to read your vimrc.

Comment: Why are you trying to `source ~/.vimrc` in your shell? This makes no sense; `.vimrc` is not a shell script.

Comment: What do you mean you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365129/why-cant-i-source-my-vimrc-after-installing-vundle with no luck? It's exactly the same problem, and the answer/comments say what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks @FDinoff , thanks for the replies . My bad, I think I miss understood the answer for the above SO question.

Comment: Thanks @melpomene , thanks for the replies . My bad :(, I think I miss understood the answer for the above SO question.

Answer (score 0):

As both `FDinoff` and `melpomene` mentioned, I can't source a `vimrc` file from bash.

Please refer to the [following SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365129/why-cant-i-source-my-vimrc-after-installing-vundle) for more details.